# Show driving directions in a flutter app

Tags: google-maps, flutter

How can we show driving directions in a flutter app?What all are the options to implement the driving directions.

Comment: take a look here : <br/><br/>
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337998/google-map-navigation-in-flutter/53571445#53571445**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading this [doc for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#directions). You can define the starting point lat/long and end point lat/long on the URL to prompt for a direction navigation. The URL should look similar to:

`comgooglemaps://?saddr={LAT},{LONG}&daddr{LAT},{LONG}&directionsmode=driving`

Then to launch the URL, you can use a plugin like [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)