# Flutter - Open Location in Maps

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Given lat and long.
Is there any fast/smart way to open maps google/apple in Flutter and head to directions ?

I'm using url_launcher for telephone calls, can i use the plugin to open link that open maps ?

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Al+qi,+ADoqi,+Giza+Governorate/@33.0523046,38.2009323,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x1458413a996ec217:0x2411f6b62d93ccc!8m2!3d30.05237!4d31.2031598';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: take a look here : <br/>
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337998/google-map-navigation-in-flutter/53571445#53571445**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes you can do that using the `url_launcher` plugin. The following code will open Google Maps when the app is installed on the phone (otherwise it will open the browser):

```
void _launchMapsUrl(double lat, double lon) async {
  final url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$lat,$lon';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: Also you can use with just address, like that: `https://www.google.com/maps/search/${Uri.encodeFull(address)}`

Comment: in iOS, this only opens the browser

Answer (score 19):

I created a plugin [Map Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher) for that.

To find installed maps on a device you can use:

```
import 'package:map_launcher/map_launcher.dart';

final availableMaps = await MapLauncher.installedMaps;
```

And then launch by calling showMarker on it

```
await availableMaps.first.showMarker(
  coords: Coords(31.233568, 121.505504),
  title: "Shanghai Tower",
  description: "Asia's tallest building",
);
```

Or just check if map available and launch it if so

```
if (await MapLauncher.isMapAvailable(MapType.google)) {
  await MapLauncher.launchMap(
    mapType: MapType.google,
    coords: coords,
    title: title,
    description: description,
  );
}
```

Comment: I got this error : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getInstalledMaps on channel map_launcher)

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: @emreuguryalcintr, just terminate running 'main.dart' and build application again

Comment: use appropeiate map for appropriate device:

`mapType: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS ? MapLauncher.MapType.apple : MapLauncher.MapType.google`

Comment: This code is working great. But, why "title" and "description" are not getting displayed in google maps for android? in iOS it is fine.

Comment: This plugin is brilliant! Thank you so much for it!

Answer (score 7):

This solution will work on both Android and iOS platforms.

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class MapsLauncher {

 static String createQueryUrl(String query) {
  var uri;

  if (kIsWeb) {
   uri = Uri.https(
      'www.google.com', '/maps/search/', {'api': '1', 'query': query});
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
   uri = Uri(scheme: 'geo', host: '0,0', queryParameters: {'q': query});
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
   uri = Uri.https('maps.apple.com', '/', {'q': query});
  } else {
   uri = Uri.https(
      'www.google.com', '/maps/search/', {'api': '1', 'query': query});
 }

 return uri.toString();
 }

static String createCoordinatesUrl(double latitude, double longitude,
  [String? label]) {
 var uri;

 if (kIsWeb) {
   uri = Uri.https('www.google.com', '/maps/search/',
      {'api': '1', 'query': '$latitude,$longitude'});
 } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
   var query = '$latitude,$longitude';

   if (label != null) query += '($label)';

   uri = Uri(scheme: 'geo', host: '0,0', queryParameters: {'q': query});
 } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
   var params = {'ll': '$latitude,$longitude'};

   if (label != null) params['q'] = label;

   uri = Uri.https('maps.apple.com', '/', params);
 } else {
   uri = Uri.https('www.google.com', '/maps/search/',
      {'api': '1', 'query': '$latitude,$longitude'});
 }

 return uri.toString();
 }

 static Future<bool> launchQuery(String query) {
  return launch(createQueryUrl(query));
 }

 static Future<bool> launchCoordinates(double latitude, double longitude,
  [String? label]) {
 return launch(createCoordinatesUrl(latitude, longitude, label));
 }
}
```

Call it like this:
MapsLauncher.launchCoordinates(
37.4220041, -122.0862462, "address");

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use address instead of lat, long, you can use the following.

Referencing https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme, `daddr` Sets the end point for directions searches

```
final url = 'comgooglemaps://?daddr=${Uri.encodeFull(address)}&directionsmode=driving';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
```

and don't forget to add to Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Open map and get directions for origin and destination https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Space+Needle+Seattle+WA&destination=Pike+Place+Market+Seattle+WA&travelmode=bicycling

Answer (score 0):

I used for this native method

```
try {
  await platform.invokeMethod('showLocation', [event.location[0], event.location[1], event.title]);
} on Exception catch (ex) {
  print('${ex.toString()}');
  ex.toString();
}
```

And in android package

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
        if (call.method == "showLocation") {
            val args = (call.arguments) as List<Any>
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:${args[0]}, ${args[1]}?z=23&q=${args[0]},${args[1]}(${args[2]})")))
            result.success(null)
        } else {
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

2022 solution

```
  void _launchMapsUrl() async {
if (_locationData == null) return;
final url =
    'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${_locationData!.latitude},${_locationData!.longitude}';

Map<String, dynamic>? params = {
  'api': '1',
  'query': '${_locationData!.latitude},${_locationData!.longitude}'
};
final uri = Uri.https(
  'www.google.com',
  '/maps/search/',
  params,
);
if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
  await launchUrl(uri);
} else {
  _showErrorDialog(
      errorText:
          'Could not launch.\nCheck please if you have Google Maps Application on your device.');
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';

void openMap(lat,long) async {
    try {
      await launchUrlString('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$lat,$long', 
                             mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(  " catched error~ $e:");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very important:

1. Long press on the app icon
2. Set as Default
3. Make sure the Open Supported Links is checked
4. `api=1` is required

Sample:

```
final queryParams = {
  'api': '1',
  'origin': origin,
  'destination': destination,
  'waypoints': waypoints.join("|"),
  'travelmode': 'driving',
};
// filter null
queryParams.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
final queryString = Uri(queryParameters: queryParams).query;
final baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/";
final url = "$baseUrl?$queryString";
_launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));


if (!await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
   throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
}
```

[image]