# How to draw routes between source and destination using Google Map in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-flutter

I recently started working on Flutter and started to build an app but now I was hoping to integrate google maps. I started to look more into `google_maps_flutter` and started to build the map but one thing I'm currently being unable to integrate is to draw the shortest route between a provided source and a destination.

I have looked into `google_maps_flutter` plugin but unable to find the implementation of the aforementioned functionality.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337998/google-map-navigation-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

If you've checked the tutorial about [Flutter - Using Google Maps and drawing Routes](https://medium.com/@stefanodecillis/flutter-using-google-maps-and-drawing-routes-100829419faf), this is a structural guide that you are looking for building an app to draw route between two places.

Aside from the package [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) as mentioned in the tutorial, you might also like to consider using the package [google_map_polyline_new](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyline_new) since [google_map_polyline](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyline) was discontinued 2 years ago.